# Datagrid Binding in code behind versus DataGrid binding in XAML

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

I am testing WPF and bindings.
I have a demo which is working fine with my bindings done in the code-behind.

Here is my XAML code and C# code.

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">

<Grid>

    <DataGrid x:Name="dgrdMaGrid" />
    <Button x:Name="button" Content="Quitter" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="355,268,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="155" Height="44" Click="button_Click"/>

</Grid>
```

c# :

```
   public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public ObservableCollection<Individu> listeIndividus = new ObservableCollection<Individu>();

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        // Load data to display
        listeIndividus = loadDummyData();

        // Build the binding
        dgrdMaGrid.DataContext = this;
        dgrdMaGrid.ItemsSource = listeIndividus;

    }
```

I am wondering how to change my XAML code to have the same result but by doing the binding inside the XAML.

I know that I should use ItemsSource="{Binding listeIndividus}", but that's not enough...

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">

<Grid>

    <DataGrid x:Name="dgrdMaGrid" ItemsSource="{Binding listeIndividus}"/>
    <Button x:Name="button" Content="Quitter" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="355,268,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="155" Height="44" Click="button_Click"/>

</Grid>
```

Thanks in advance for your tips

Vincent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where you say "// Build the binding", that's not a binding. You're not creating an instance of the `Binding` class. That's just an assignment, and the difference matters.

OK, lecture over, now to fix your code.

First, you can't bind to a field, only to a property. So `listeIndividus` needs a getter:

```
public ObservableCollection<Individu> listeIndividus { get; } = new ObservableCollection<Individu>();
```

Second, this *is* a `Binding`, but you don't have a viewmodel, so it won't work as it is. This binding will look at `Window.DataContext` for a property named `listeIndividus`. Since `Window.DataContext` is null, it won't find it. `Window.DataContext` would be the viewmodel, if you had one.

```
<DataGrid x:Name="dgrdMaGrid" ItemsSource="{Binding listeIndividus}"/>
```

So tell it where to really look -- on the Window itself:

```
<DataGrid 
    x:Name="dgrdMaGrid" 
    ItemsSource="{Binding listeIndividus, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Window}}"
    />
```

Comment: Woww thanks for your post. With your comments, my sample is working fine now and I have a better understanding. Now, I am wondering if my sample with the binding in the code behind was really correct (despite it was working fine...). Thanks Ed !

Comment: @VincentMontagnon Well, "correct", I dunno. If it worked it worked. Taking the long view, though, the MVVM viewmodel/XAML-binding approach has a steep learning curve but it's much more powerful and flexible.

Comment: @Ed...I agree with that. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Thanks a lot, you saved me a lot of time!